# Extending Minibuffer Message for save-buffer

Tags: emacs, elisp, minibuffer

Is it possible the extend the minibuffer message for `save-buffer` to instead print something like

```
Wrote /home/per/Work/justd/fs.d (L lines, T tokens, C chars)
```

If so what hook/string should I modify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to live with the message "Wrote ..." since this can come from several different handlers and there it is hard-coded. But you can add your own message afterwards:

```lisp
(add-hook 'after-save-hook (lambda ()
               (message "Saved buffer %s. (%d lines)"
                 (buffer-file-name)
                 (count-lines (point-min) (point-max)))))
```